# RemoteConfig Without Internet Giving Empty String

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-remote-config

I have this class that I use to get the remote configs from Firebase.

```
internal object MyConfig {

    const val KEY = "test_key"

    private var remoteConfig: FirebaseRemoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance()

    init {
        val configSettings = FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.Builder()
            .setMinimumFetchIntervalInSeconds(3600)
            .build()
        remoteConfig.setConfigSettingsAsync(configSettings)
        remoteConfig.fetchAndActivate()
    }

    fun getKey(): String {
        return mRemoteConfig.getString(KEY)
    }
}
```

This works ok but if I don't have internet when the app opens then the key will be `""`. When I get internet back the key is still `""` when I call the `getKey()`.

How can I make it so that if the key comes back as the `""` then the value is not stored in the `remoteConfig`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no settings or configurations for individual keys or values.  When you get a value from Remote Config, you will get that same value every time until the next fetch possibly changes it with a new value from the server.  When a fetch completes, it will contain all the current values from server, or none of them if the fetch fails, and never an incomplete subset of values.

Remote Config doesn't automatically try to fetch new values when your app comes online.  If you want it to fetch again, you will have to write code for that, which is very much possible.

Comment: if I do something like `remoteConfig.fetchAndActivate()` how can I know if it did it successfully? I am thinking check if it failed and then when internet comes back try again.

Comment: You can check for errors on the call to fetchAndActivate() as described in the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/use-config-android